# CSS Animation and Columns in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I've encountered some trouble with animating icons in Google Chrome. I tested this in Safari and Firefox, and my code works there, so I'm not sure if this is an error on my part or an issue with the browser. I'm coding icons in columns so that they stack evenly in a responsive layout, but when I put them in columns, all icons except the first one move down the page.

Any help either identifying what I'm doing wrong or helping to find a workaround would be appreciated. I cut out the media queries in my code for the sake of simplicity posting it here.

```css
#pptoc {
  background-color: #3f72a5;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a1c0d0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-columns: 6;
  -moz-columns: 6;
  columns: 6;
}

#pptoc img {}

#pptoc a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1c0d0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

.pptocitem:hover {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.2s 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="pptoc">
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im1" class="pptocitem"><br>part 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im2" class="pptocitem"><span class="test1"><br>part 2</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im3" class="pptocitem"><br>part 3</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im4" class="pptocitem"><br>part 4</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im5" class="pptocitem"><br>part 5</a></div>
<div class="part 6"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im6" class="pptocitem"><br>part 6</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` instead of CSS `columns` and those elements will stay put. Flexbox also gives you more positioning options.

BTW, you have a bunch of unclosed `a` tags and an unclosed `span`

```css
#pptoc {
  background-color: #3f72a5;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a1c0d0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#pptoc a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1c0d0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

.pptocitem:hover {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.2s 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="pptoc">
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im1" class="pptocitem"><br>part 1
  </div>
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im2" class="pptocitem"><span class="test1"><br>part 2</span></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im3" class="pptocitem"><br>part 3</div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im4" class="pptocitem"><br>part 4</div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im5" class="pptocitem"><br>part 5</div>
<div class="part 6"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im6" class="pptocitem"><br>part 6</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help; I'll use this instead! And thanks for the catch on the A tags as well––they probably got messed up when I was taking everything extra out.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use flexbox as suggested by Michael Coker, or make use `will-change` CSS property, that hints the browser to expect certain changes in a particular element, and prepare itself for that change.

See how it fixed the flickering of `.pptocitem` when hovered:

```css
#pptoc {
  background-color: #3f72a5;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a1c0d0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-columns: 6;
  -moz-columns: 6;
  columns: 6;
}

#pptoc img {}

#pptoc a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1c0d0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

.pptocitem {
  will-change: transform;
}

.pptocitem:hover {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.2s 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="pptoc">
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im1" class="pptocitem"><br>part 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im2" class="pptocitem"><span class="test1"><br>part 2</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im3" class="pptocitem"><br>part 3</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im4" class="pptocitem"><br>part 4</a></div>
<div class="pptocsect"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im5" class="pptocitem"><br>part 5</a></div>
<div class="part 6"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=im6" class="pptocitem"><br>part 6</a></div>
```

Cheers!